# Product Map Converse

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I understand the proofs $a$ $b$ $c$ and the first part of $d$. What I don’t get is the last sentence that proves the converse of $d$. Can someone please tell me why the converse is true?

*This proof was found in Michael Artin Algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s spelled out what he’s trying to say: If $f \colon H × K → G$ is an isomorphism, then

- $1 = H∩K$ if and only if $0 = f^{-1}(H) ∩ f^{-1}(K) = (H × 0) ∩ (0 × K)$.
- $G = HK$ if and only if $H × K = f^{-1}(HK) = f^{-1}(H)f^{-1}(K) = (H × 0) + (0 × K)$.
- $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $f^{-1}(H) = H × 0$ is normal in $H × K$.
- $K$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $f^{-1}(K) = 0 × K$ is normal in $H × K$.

This is very tedious to write down, but fairly obvious. Isomorphisms of groups obviously preserve all set- and group-theoretic properties, so they preserve the properties that are needed to be checked here.